# X509Certificate2 extension methods, issue with nCipher KSP

Tags: .net, x509certificate2, cng

I'm having issues in acquiring private key handles when the key is backed by nCipher KSP. For example when calling

```
cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
```

the call succeeds and the key is usable, however this call generates 5 (five) entries in Windows EventLog:

> ERROR: NCCNG_NCryptGetKeyProperty: unsupported flags 0x40000000 (supported 0x00000040)

a quick research suggested that .NET API calls `NCryptGetProperty` with `NCRYPT_PERSIST_ONLY_FLAG` flags in `dwFlags` parameter and nCipher KSP does not support `NCRYPT_PERSIST_ONLY_FLAG`. I was unable to find a way to suppress these errors in nCipher configuration.

Is this a .NET or nCipher issue? What are other workarounds apart from directly introping `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey`, `NCryptOpenStorageProvider` and `NCryptOpenKey` CryptoAPI functions?

Comment: Logging them as an error sounds like an nCipher bug.  I don't think there's any way that .NET can detect a KSP being that angry about a valid flag, and I'd guess that NCryptOpenKey followed by sending that value to CngKey/ECDsaCng will give the same reports to the event log.  If you see a way that we can reliably cause less spam to the event log, please open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/

Comment: First problem is that the event is generated 5 times for some unknown reason. By calling `NCryptOpenKey` without flags, or only `NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG` flag in `dwFlags` parameter it doesn't cause any issues nor event entries. I'm not sure why .NET pass `NCRYPT_PERSIST_ONLY_FLAG` to NCrypt functions.